# SQLException - Unexpected parameter marker. What is it?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, jtds

I am facing an error

> java.sql.SQLException: Unexpected parameter marker at position 128

while I run my application.

I'm using SQL and values to the query being passed as parameters. I want to know what exactly does it mean/convey to the programmer/debugger? Why does it occur? How do I resolve it?

Information about the DB:

```
driver-name=jTDS Type 4 JDBC Driver for MS SQL Server and Sybase
driver-version=1.2
DB=Microsoft SQL Server v12.00.4100
```

Comment: is it sql-server or oracle?

Comment: @ydoow: SQL Server I have mentioned in the INFO also.

Comment: What is your query, and how are you invoking it?  Please show your code.